# Google Analytics API for Python

Tags: python, analytics

How can I get data of all 30 days in a list (in python) from Google Analytics API in order to plot a line chart and see a trend?

```
 def get_users(service,profile_id):
      active_users =  service.data().ga().get(
      ids='ga:'+profile_id,
      start_date = '2018-09-01',
      end_date = '2018-09-27',
      metrics= 'ga:users',
      start_index=1,
      max_results= 30).execute()
```

this is my current code and it just gives me one number, when I want all users for each day in month and save that as a list or pandas dataframe.
Any ideas????

Answer (score 0):

Add `dimensions='ga:date'` in the parameters of your get request.